# GoogleMap com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.getMap()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, google-maps, nullpointerexception

I have implemented google maps, it works fine until I exit the map Activity to go to another Activity and when I return back to the map activity, it then crashes. I think this happens when the location listener tries to get user position while the FIRST map is still loading or the maps are overloading each other, so how can I destroy my first map when I leave my activity under onPause and onDestroy?

Note that my class extends Activity and not Fragment or FragmentActivity and I am not using MapView.

```
public class ActivityLocate extends Activity
private GoogleMap map;

...

    private void initilizeMap() {

    lm = (LocationManager)ActivityLocate.this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    ll = new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (map == null) {
                map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

                // check if map is created successfully or not
                if (map == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Failed to load map", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            longitude = location.getLongitude();

            latitudeString = String.valueOf(latitude);
            longitudeString = String.valueOf(longitude);

            map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            if (autoCamera.equals("1"))
            {
                map.animateCamera( CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(4.0f) );                
                CameraUpdate center= CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)); // zoom to current location
                CameraUpdate zoom=CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(8);
                map.moveCamera(center);
                map.animateCamera(zoom);

                autoCamera = "0";
            }
            else
            {
                //don't position camera again to allow user to self navigate
            }

            accessWebService_getMarkers();

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    };

    //LOCATION CHANGE OPTIONS
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 60000, 1, ll); //every minute / meter

}
```

Lifecycles:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (map == null) {
        try {
            initilizeMap();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

}
```

Error:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.getMap()' on a null object reference
```

Comment: Your Fragment can't be found. If the activity is re-created, so is the Fragment - it won't have a map

Comment: Also, if you make the Activity implement `LocationListener`, your code would look a bit cleaner

Answer (score 1):

Google map V2 doesn't use getMap now, it uses `getMapAsync(this);`

follow this link [Google Map V2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/) and it will solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

Solved, Credit to:

[Showing current location in Google Maps using API V2 with SupportMapFragment](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/showing-current-location-in-google-maps-using-api-v2-with-supportmapfragment/)